# What's Wrong with this Java Code?

Tags: java, file, loops, for-loop

This doesn't give me any errors, but when I compile it returns(I DID declare all of the variables/arrays):

line 48:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at modmaker.GuiBlocks2.main(GuiBlocks2.java:48)

```
package modmaker;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class GuiBlocks2 extends JFrame {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public JFileChooser filePath;
FileEditor fileeditor = new FileEditor();
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
static String files;
static String fileList = "";
static String path = "ModMaker"; 
static File folder = new File(path);
static File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 
String[] allFile = fileList.split(":");
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GuiBlocks2 frame = new GuiBlocks2();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    // Directory path here
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
    {

    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())
    {

        if (files.endsWith(".png") || files.endsWith(".PNG"))
        {
            fileList += files + ":";
            files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            System.out.println(files);
        }
    }
}
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */

public GuiBlocks2() {
    setTitle("Linkseyi's ModMaker");
    setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);


    JButton btnGenerateFiles = new JButton("Generate Files");
    btnGenerateFiles.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fileeditor.addBlock();
        }
    });
    btnGenerateFiles.setBounds(151, 120, 123, 51);
    getContentPane().add(btnGenerateFiles);

    final JComboBox textureChooseBox = new JComboBox(allFile);
    textureChooseBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String imgName = (String)textureChooseBox.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println(imgName);
        }
    });
    textureChooseBox.setBounds(151, 75, 123, 20);
    getContentPane().add(textureChooseBox);

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Choose Texture");
    label1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    label1.setBounds(169, 38, 123, 14);
    getContentPane().add(label1);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 233);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Comment: Where is `files` set? Make sure that listOfFiles and files are actually being set before using them.

Comment: It gives you that exception when you compile?  Or when you try to run it?

Comment: Which line of the code you provide corresponds to the line 48 of the error?

Comment: Well, the only thing on line 48 (according to your edit) is `listOfFiles`, therefore, it's `null`

Comment: Even from the code snippet shown, I recommend taking a different approach (though it is unrelated to the immediate problem).  Use a `(java.io.)FileFilter` or `FilenameFilter` as an argument to `File.listFiles()`.  That way there is no need to filter them later.

Answer (score 3):

Listoffiles was not instantiated or files.  Hard to say since we don't know what line 48 is.  Update.  With your new code modmaker cannot be found that is why it is null.  You probably want /modmaker

Comment: @Jeff - unfortunately we don't have ESP. Without the full stack trace and code, we can only make guesses.

Comment: not necessarily.  It could be anything inside of `listOfFiles`, it could be `files`, it could aslo be `fileList`.  Point: Not enough information to answer.

Comment: Ironically, someone downvoted the correct answer. (See OP's latest edit - listOfFiles is line 48, and therefore null)

Comment: My answer still stands that you didn't instatiate listoffiles

Comment: @Woot4Moo  I'm with you on this.  Would the down-voter care to share a reason?

Answer (score 3):

In line 48, `listOfFiles` is `null`. It is defined as

```
static File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

From the [Java API docs:](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)

```
public File[] listFiles()
```

> Returns: An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and
>   directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The
>   array will be empty if the directory is empty. **Returns null if this
>   abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error
>   occurs.**

That seems to be your error...

Comment: As well as reading exception messages and trying to check why they were thrown...

Answer (score 1):

```
folder.listOfFiles();
```

didn't return back an array, it returned something that was null.  So when you hit

```
static File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

the File arrray, listOfFiles was assigned to null.  That means on line 48

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
```

the subportion of that line

```
listOfFiles.length
```

throws a null pointer exception, because you just asked for

```
'null'.length
```

and null has no methods or properties to read.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `listOfFiles` is null.

Add check before the loop:

```
if (listOfFiles == null) {
    return;
}
```